# jQuery - open selectbox on click on li, when option chosen trigger checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a new problem I can't sort out after some testing and researching.

I have several select-boxes nested in several ul>li's like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
<span class="select">

<input type="checkbox" name="kurse[]" value="" />

<select name="numbers1"  value="">
  <option value="">Bitte w&auml;hle eine Option...</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
</span>

    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="kurse[]" value="" />
<span class="select">

<select name="numbers2"  value="">
  <option value="">Bitte w&auml;hle eine Option...</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
</span>

    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="kurse[]" value="" />
<span class="select">

<select name="numbers3" value="">
  <option value="">Bitte w&auml;hle eine Option...</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Right now my Javascript triggers the nested checkbox by clicking on an li. This is the script:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').siblings();
    jQuery(this).find('input').prop('checked', function () {
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
```

I had to add the select-boxes and now I want to open the select-box nested in the li which has been clicked on. After an option has been chosen I want the checkbox "clicked" which is nested inside the same li.

By editing the code above I ended in something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    jQuery(this).find('select').prop(function () {
        jQuery(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

But this is not working because of my lack of knowledge in jQuery.

Any suggestions on that? Is it possible with some jQuery, or do I need to change to **Chosen** or something similar?

Here's a fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/QHv6B/1/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made an edit of your jQuery code, and changed two lines in your html to get it working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/QHv6B/2/)

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').siblings();
});

jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    jQuery(this).find('select').prop(function () {
        jQuery(this).trigger('click');
    });
});

jQuery(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    var selectedItem = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    var checkBox = $(this).prev();
    if (typeof selectedItem === 'undefined' || selectedItem === "") {
        alert("You must select an option");
        $(checkBox).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(checkBox).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi PalinDrome555 and thank you for your answer; this is nearly what i wanted to achieve! Right now the checkbox gets checked when choosing an option, what is good already! But is it possible to "open" the select-box to choose an option by clicking on the li?

Comment: I'm afraid that will not work, the only way is actually to click the select box to open it. The Closet your going to get to that is by this
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/QHv6B/3/)

Comment: The fiddle looks quite good, thx again so far! gonna test it in my "environment" and give feedback!

Comment: tested this in my environment and had to make some edits to get it working! But I ran into another problem...is it possible to add the chosen-option-value to the value of another hidden field dynamically? right now those ul-lists and checkboxes are inside a form. On form submit and successful validation the chosen-option-values don't get submitted, on validation error, filling mandatory fields and re-submit the chosen-option-values get transmitted. On first option-choose the value of the select-box nneds to be added inside the hidden-input-value dynamically!

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow not near my pc at the moment.

Comment: thx PalinDrome...i tried a bit and got it somehow working in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LYz36/1/

As you can see the text-field gets updated on chosing a different select. But this doesn't work in my form, the new value must be "written" dynamically inside the html-source to get transmitted on form-validation and to send the chosen values inside a confirmation mail.

Comment: Hmm... is it really necessary to have text fields updated, I assume you want to have the select boxes / checkboxes validated by choosing either option 1 - 3 before submitting the form, and by the way you haven't included the form in the fiddle. Are you using a plugin to do the validation or are you doing it manually?

Comment: it's a bit complicated; i'm using this form inside the CMS-system MODX and the FormIt-Plugin for forms and validation (though some validators are scripted by myself). I guess the problem is the different select-boxes; when I try to use the form with only one select-box the value gets submitted immediately; but when I use several select-boxes the form needs to get sent twice, because only after first validation-error the values get added to the html-source, then they are transmitted. Maybe a link (in private) is handy?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that CMS or that plugin, Yes you can send me a link, but I think the best thing to do would be to form a new question specifying what you need to accomplish. Somebody with knowledge of the CMS and FormIt plugin could be of more help to you.

Comment: yeah, you're right...I made a new thread in a MODX-forum, hopefully there is anyone with a hint: http://forums.modx.com/thread/92550/multiple-select-boxes---values-transmitted-only-on-2nd-submit#dis-post-505687
Thx a lot again for your help! I'll rate your answer as correct, because it lead me to the correct direction.